# Google Drive API returning null values

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive API to get lists of files and I get most of the values as null except name, MimeType, id and Kind. What am I doing wrong?
I am really looking for modifiedTime and lastModifyingUser and also add this to the request but it did not work

```
listRequest.Fields = "files(lastModifyingUser,modifiedTime)"
```

Below is the code I am using

```
<pre>
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest1 = service.Files.List();
                                listRequest1.PageSize = 100;
                                listRequest1.Q = "'" + file.Id + "' " + "in parents";
                                listRequest.OrderBy = "'modifiedDate desc'";
</pre>
```

It comes back with lot of files. Below is what one of the file looks like

```
<pre>
{Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File}
    AppProperties: null
    Capabilities: null
    ContentHints: null
    CreatedTime: null
    CreatedTimeRaw: null
    Description: null
    ETag: null
    ExplicitlyTrashed: null
    FileExtension: null
    FolderColorRgb: null
    FullFileExtension: null
    HeadRevisionId: null
    IconLink: null
    Id: "0B1VioX_6dSXKZ2R2bDdKZDVuTjQ"
    ImageMediaMetadata: null
    IsAppAuthorized: null
    Kind: "drive#file"
    LastModifyingUser: null
    Md5Checksum: null
    MimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    ModifiedByMeTime: null
    ModifiedByMeTimeRaw: null
    ModifiedTime: null
    ModifiedTimeRaw: null
    Name: "Quarterly VC PowerPoint"
    OriginalFilename: null
    OwnedByMe: null
    Owners: null
    Parents: null
    Permissions: null
    Properties: null
    QuotaBytesUsed: null
    Shared: null
    SharedWithMeTime: null
    SharedWithMeTimeRaw: null
    SharingUser: null
    Size: null
    Spaces: null
    Starred: null
    ThumbnailLink: null
    Trashed: null
    Version: null
    VideoMediaMetadata: null
    ViewedByMe: null
    ViewedByMeTime: null
    ViewedByMeTimeRaw: null
    ViewersCanCopyContent: null
    WebContentLink: null
    WebViewLink: null
    WritersCanShare: null
</pre>
```

Comment: Same problem here with PHP SDK V3

Comment: hey, did you find solution for this? having same problem on public folder image

Answer (score 0):

Try `listRequest.Fields = @"files(*)";`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Asterisk selection should only be used during development as it will most likely be unnecessary to load all of the fields all of the time. In production code you should always select specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this code:

```
        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = Dservice.Files.List();
        listRequest.Q = "'root' in parents";
        listRequest.Fields= @"files(*)";
        var files = listRequest.Execute();
        google_sheet_files.Clear();
        foreach (Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file in files.Files)
        {
            if (file.MimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet")

                google_sheet_files.Add(new googlesheet(file.Id, file.Name, file.ModifiedTime ?? DateTime.Now, file.LastModifyingUser.EmailAddress,file.ModifiedByMeTime ?? DateTime.Now));




        }
```

Comment: You're using it and...? Is that a solution? Please be specific.